# How to convert factor to numeric in R without NAs introduced by coercion warning message

Tags: r

I have a data which contains factor class , so while converting it to numeric , i'm getting this warning message . following code i've written in R to convert factor into numeric

```
class(usedcars$Price)
[1] "factor"

e <- paste(usedcars$Price)
e <- as.numeric(paste(usedcars$Price))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Guys all the data is converted into "NA" but class is numeric.
Could anyone help me out to get rid of this NA warning message while converting a factor to numeric in R?

Comment: Is your question: How do I convert a number stored as a factor to numeric? If so, you don't just want to get rid of the warning, presumably... does `e <- as.numeric(as.character(usedcars$Price))` help?

Comment: @alexwhan-yes it convert the data to numeric but all of my data is changed to NA

Comment: OK, perhaps posting your data would be a good idea...?

Comment: @alexwhan - friend it contains 72000 rows :(

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Post `str(usedcars)`, `head(usedcars)` etc

Comment: `str(usedcars)`

 $ RefId                            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ IsBadBuy                         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Price                             : Factor w/ 10316 levels  "0","10000","10001",..: 7882 7887
 $ PurchDate                        : Factor w/ 518 levels "01-04...

Comment: Why is `paste` here when you just want to convert factors into numeric?

Comment: @Metrics `> all(paste(1:10)==as.character(1:10))
[1] TRUE` even though is not 'best practice'

Comment: @sam in place of writing a comment please edit the question and post the result of `dput(head(usedcars))`

Answer (score 19):

This happens when you use `as.numeric` on non-numeric variables.

my guess is that your numbers have "," in them (for example 1,285)
so first make your factors "clean" with `db <- gsub(",","",db)` and then run `as.numeric(db)`

Comment: The simplest answer.  I spent an hour looking at all the other complicated ones.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I know this was asked a long time ago but since it doesn't have an accepted answer I would like to add this:

```
e <- as.numeric(as.factor(usedcars$Price))
```

When paste is being used, it is essentially converting the price into character and then to numeric and it doesn't work mostly because of the properties of a dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to replicate your problem:

```
set.seed(1)
a <- factor(sample(1:100, 10))
> a
 [1] 27 37 57 89 20 86 97 62 58 6 
Levels: 6 20 27 37 57 58 62 86 89 97
```

The alexwhan comment is fine actually:

```
> as.numeric(as.character(a))
 [1] 27 37 57 89 20 86 97 62 58  6
```

Even if your data needs to be `trim()ed` it would work anyway:

```
> paste( " ", a, " ")
 [1] "  27  " "  37  " "  57  " "  89  " "  20  " "  86  " "  97  " "  62  " "  58  " "  6  " 
> as.numeric(paste( " ", a, " "))
 [1] 27 37 57 89 20 86 97 62 58  6
```

SO the only explanation is you have some (unexpected) character in **all** your numbers

```
> as.numeric(paste(a, "a"))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

If you can't see any letter the following happened to me:

```
> paste( intToUtf8(160), a, intToUtf8(160))
 [1] "  27  " "  37  " "  57  " "  89  " "  20  " "  86  " "  97  " "  62  " "  58  " "  6  " 
> as.numeric(paste( intToUtf8(160), a, intToUtf8(160)))
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

intToUtf8(32) is the usual white space from the keyboard (like above some lines) but the number 160 is something that looks similar what is another different thing, which `as.numeric` (and also `trim` from `gdata`) doesn't recognise and returns
 `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try `retype` from the hablar package. If the problem is commas instead of dots, it replaces them with dots. Example:

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(a = as.factor(c("1,56", "5,87")))

df %>% retype()
```

gives you:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 1
      a
  <dbl>
1  1.56
2  5.87
```